# Importing bg image for jumbotron - bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to import a background image for my jumbotron. Here is my code.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7e1d7k9/1/)

```
       <header class="jumbotron">

          <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

          <div class="container">
              <div class="row row-header">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                      <h1>City of Larissa</h1>
                      <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                      <p>More than 8000 years of history</p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                       <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                       <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </header>
```

and

```
.jumbotron {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 70px 30px;
  background: url('img/alcazar1.png');
  color: floralwhite;
}
```

However, when I import that image through css,it can not be shown. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be You need to check the **ImagePath** for the Jumbotron Class in CSS.